# Implement part of c source code

Tags: python, c, mouse

My goal is to implement a program that simply returns the current mouse position (without opening up any windows, and regardless of what is running). After searching for this, the closest and simplest implementation I could find was through [autopy](https://github.com/msanders/autopy/#readme), a python library for doing this sort of thing.

The function 'get_pos()' which returns the current mouse position. See the documentation [here](http://www.autopy.org/documentation/api-reference/mouse.html). I simply want to implement the 'get_pos()' function on its own (because that's all I need to include from autopy for the program I am developing).

In a github repo, I have searched through the source code of autopy and I have come to the following conclusions. Calling 'get_pos()' causes the *mouse_get_pos function to occur (see complete code [here](https://github.com/msanders/autopy/blob/38e5ecc7cf6e3a19bd37935e577984312e0930a2/src/autopy-mouse-module.c)):

```
/* Syntax: get_pos() => tuple (x, y) */
/* Description: Returns a tuple `(x, y)` of the current mouse position. */
static PyObject *mouse_get_pos(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);
```

This function seems to call 'getMousePos':

```
static PyObject *mouse_get_pos(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    MMPoint pos = getMousePos();
    return Py_BuildValue("kk", pos.x, pos.y);
}
```

Which is located in the [mouse.c](https://github.com/msanders/autopy/blob/38e5ecc7cf6e3a19bd37935e577984312e0930a2/src/mouse.c) header file:

```
MMPoint getMousePos()
{
#if defined(IS_MACOSX)
    CGEventRef event = CGEventCreate(NULL);
    CGPoint point = CGEventGetLocation(event);
    CFRelease(event);

    return MMPointFromCGPoint(point);
#elif defined(USE_X11)
    int x, y; /* This is all we care about. Seriously. */
    Window garb1, garb2; /* Why you can't specify NULL as a parameter */
    int garb_x, garb_y;  /* is beyond me. */
    unsigned int more_garbage;

    Display *display = XGetMainDisplay();
    XQueryPointer(display, XDefaultRootWindow(display), &garb1, &garb2,
              &x, &y, &garb_x, &garb_y, &more_garbage);

    return MMPointMake(x, y);
#elif defined(IS_WINDOWS)
    POINT point;
    GetCursorPos(&point);

    return MMPointFromPOINT(point);
#endif
}
```

This code seems to include a method of returning the mouse position in all operating systems, which is what I'm trying to implement in my program. How can I get this c function to work properly on my system, so that I can implement it in my program?

**EDIT:** I tried simply compiling mouse.c by using 'gcc mouse.c', and I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFRelease", referenced from:
      _moveMouse in ccVkh5f7.o
      _getMousePos in ccVkh5f7.o
      _toggleMouse in ccVkh5f7.o
  "_CGEventCreate", referenced from:
      _getMousePos in ccVkh5f7.o
  "_CGEventCreateMouseEvent", referenced from:
      _moveMouse in ccVkh5f7.o
      _toggleMouse in ccVkh5f7.o
  "_CGEventGetLocation", referenced from:
      _getMousePos in ccVkh5f7.o
  "_CGEventPost", referenced from:
      _moveMouse in ccVkh5f7.o
      _toggleMouse in ccVkh5f7.o
  "_deadbeef_rand", referenced from:
      _smoothlyMoveMouse in ccVkh5f7.o
  "_getMainDisplaySize", referenced from:
      _smoothlyMoveMouse in ccVkh5f7.o
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does this make any underlying problem apparent?

Comment: mouse.c is no header file.

Comment: Do you want to implement it in pure python? Probably not possible. So you would need a C (or C++) compiler, compile the autopy part you need, and interface that. Why can't you just use autopy, even when you don't need all its features?

Comment: "How can I get this c function to work properly on my system, so that I can implement it in my program?" What's your system? What's not working properly?

Comment: @Sebastian I edited the question to include the error that occurs when I compile mouse.c

Comment: @Sebastian: You _could_ write the code in Python with just the stdlib, using `ctypes` to access the appropriate DLL/so/framework.

Comment: It would help if you showed us your complete code. This can't be the whole `mouse.c` file, because it refers to all kinds of things that aren't defined or included from elsewhere.

Comment: @abarnert I have a link to the whole [mouse.c](https://github.com/msanders/autopy/blob/38e5ecc7cf6e3a19bd37935e577984312e0930a2/src/mouse.c) file right here and in the original question body

Comment: @cbsm1th: So you're trying to just compile that file, as-is, as a program? That's not going to be very useful. For one thing, it clearly depends on code from other source files in `autopy`, so you're going to have to compile those too. And they will depend on other code as well, so you have to do so recursively. At which point you're just building `autopy`, and you already know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem on your Mac is that you're compiling code that uses various frameworks, and you're not linking those frameworks. `_CFRelease` comes from CoreFoundation, `_CGEventCreate` from Quartz, etc.

So, you can't just write `gcc mouse.c`. If you write, say, `gcc mouse.c -framework CoreFoundation`, you'll see some of the errors go away. If you add all of the right flags, you'll see all of them go away.

On the Mac, presumably your `mouse.c` (or a header it uses) already includes the header files from those frameworks, or it wouldn't have even compiled, so you wouldn't have even gotten those linker errors. In that case, it's pretty easy to guess which frameworks you need to include: `#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>` means you need `-framework CoreFoundation`.

Alternatively, you can just search Apple's developer documentation for each of the functions that fails; it will tell you, at the top of each page, which framework the missing function is in.

There are probably other things you want to include. For example, if you want to distribute a binary, rather than source that each user has to build, you probably want to build against an SDK, rather than against the local files.

---

But you're going to have the exact same problem on every other platform, so you're going to have to solve it there as well. And other platforms don't have frameworks; there's no obviously one-to-one mapping between header files and `-l` libraries on linux.

Obviously `autopy` has already solved this problem, so its setup.py/configure/Makefile/whatever will already tell you all the things you need to link to on each platform (although it may include a whole bunch of other stuff you *don't* need).

---

The last error is a little different. It's complaining that you haven't defined a `main` function. Every C program has to have a `main` function. (If you were trying to build a static or shared library instead of a program, you have to tell GCC to do that.)

---

[Here](http://pastebin.com/yVG12cy8) you can see a version hacked up to work on OS X.